# Как правильно разделить backend PHP и клиент Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Всем привет ! Получил задание сделать небольшое api   (back Laravel, клиент Vue) .Подскажите как правильно поступить с роутингом- делать на Ларе или подключить Vue роутер и каждый route -это компонент(+axios)? Как должно быть по науке? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если у вас spa, то второй вариант, если mpa - первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать роуты только в laravel, то при переходе на новую страницу она будет каждый раз перезагружаться, если это устраивает то я бы остановился на таком варианте, как на более простом.
Если же вы хотите делать spa на vue, то можете использовать vue router, но чтобы не возникал конфликт роутов то для api можно сделать роуты которые начинаются с ‘/api’, а для страниц начинать например с ‘/web’ с последующей обработкой vue router